# Handling Firebase "Tasks" and implement Manager Classes (for Firebase) in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing the code for a game whose server-side is totally based on Firebase. I expect to use Auth, Database, InstanceID, Messaging and Cloud Functions in the game. 
Being a novice C# Programmer, I encountered with C# "Tasks" first time with Firebase. 
I'm going to use Database for a lot of times (like Score Update, Friends Requests, Chat, Friend Did this, Friend Did that). 
I mostly feel comfortable with Singleton Pattern (GameManagers, EnemyManagers, SoundManagers etc..). 
But with Firebase, since most of its calls are asynchronous and implemented via Tasks. I think I need to workaround differently to implement Managers.

For example, I need to send a Friend Request to a specific friend. The UIManager is a script that deals with UI events etc. I'd like to call Method from this script to another Manager (say FriendsManager). But I need to first check if this friend is already friend of mine from Database or Not? So, what I would do is

```
class UIManager
{
   void OnFriendRequestClicked(string friendId)
   {
      bool userExists = FriendsManager.instance.UserExists(friendId);
      if(userExists)
            // Proceed with Sending Request
               FriendsManager.instance.SendRequest(friendId);
       else 
          // Show a Dialogue that User ID is invalid
          ShowError("User Id is invalid");

       // NOTE: The above code block of "condition" is executed before 
       // the UserID is validated from FriendsManager
       // I know its because of Task. But how can I alter this code 
       // to do something in the similar pattern? 
   }
}

class FriendsManager
{
   bool UserExists(string userIdToCheck)
   {
    reference.Child("users").Child(userIdToCheck).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(
  task=>
   {
       if(task.IsCompleted)
         {
             if(task.Result == null)
                  return false;    // (expected) Return false to Method "UserExists"
             else 
                  return true;    //(expected) Return true to Method "UserExists" 

       // But this won't actually return "bool" to the method,
      // it actually returns to its own "Task"
     //NOTE: -> How to Return from here to the Method? 
   )};   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Instead of waiting/blocking while the data is being loaded, the app continues. And then when the data is available, it calls your callback.

You can most easily see this with some logging statements:

```
Debug.Log("Before starting to load data");

reference.Child("users").Child(userIdToCheck).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task=> {
   Debug.Log("Data loaded");
});

Debug.Log("After starting to load data");
```

When you run this code it logs:

> Before starting to load data
>
> After starting to load data
>
> Data loaded

That is probably not what you expected, but explains perfectly why you can't return a value from within the callback: the `UserExists` has already finished at that point.

This means that any code that needs access to the data from the database, must be *inside* the `ContinueWith` block (or be called from there).

---

The simplest approach is to move the code from your `OnFriendRequestClicked` into `UserExists`:

```
bool UserExists(string userIdToCheck) {
  reference.Child("users").Child(userIdToCheck).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task=>
{
   if(task.IsCompleted)
   {
       if(task.Result == null)
           ShowError("User Id is invalid");
       else 
           FriendsManager.instance.SendRequest(friendId);
   )};   
}
```

You can then call this function without the `if` after it.

---

The above approach works great, but means that your `UserExists` method is no longer reusable in different cases. To make it reusable again, you can pass your own callback interface into `UserExists`.

For example, using `Task`:

```
bool UserExists(string userIdToCheck, Action<bool> callback) {
  reference.Child("users").Child(userIdToCheck).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task=>
{
   if(task.IsCompleted)
   {
       if(task.Result == null)
           callback(false);
       else 
           callback(true);
   )};   
}
```

And then to invoke it:

```
FriendsManager.instance.UserExists(friendId, userExists => {
    if(userExists)
        FriendsManager.instance.SendRequest(friendId);
    else 
        ShowError("User Id is invalid");
})
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Own Callbacks are what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, don't know if these Callbacks support C# 4.0 or not?

Comment: I had another option to use async. But async was introduced later in C# 5.0. I will check out if custom callbacks are supported in C# 4.0 or not. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: As far as I could determine this was all pretty established C# stuff. But it's definitely been a few years since I wrote any C#, so there may be syntax errors. If you encounter any, please comment or (event better) click edit to fix them. :)